# Return - Metodo chamado no form1, e return no form2

Tags: c#, .net

Galera boa noite, uma duvida.
Tenho um form1 que chama uma classe e um metodo, enviando ha esse metodo dois parametros string, esse metodo processa, e me retorna um valor int.

A minha duvida é, é possivel eu chamar esse metodo no form1 e o retorno dele ser no form2?

Se sim, como?
se não, oque devo fazer? preciso dos parametros do form1 para executar o metodo.

Obrigado

Comment: Me parece que você está aprendendo programar o fluxo de um aplicativo com interface gráfica. Para podermos ajudar, experimente contar a história real do que você precisa fazer. Por exemplo: você precisa de um "wizard" (sequência de formulários pedindo informações para o usuário)? Ou o form2 é o resultado do processamento de form1 (como se o primeiro fosse um filtro)?

Comment: @Caffé está certo. Você precisa formar melhor sua pergunta e dizer, por exemplo, se estes forms são criados na mesma thread. Se form2 é chamado por form1 é fácil, por exemplo se o processamento é terminado antes de chamar o form2 este resultado pode ser usado como parâmetro.  Se o form2 é chamado antes do processamento terminar este pode checar (de tempos em tempos?) uma propriedade pública do form1 (setada pela resultado do processamento). Já trabalhar com threads é meio complicado para um iniciante. Enfim depende muito do seu cenário.

Comment: muito obrigado pelos comentários, sim estou começando a me aventurar no mundo da programação, então, estou realizando uma tela de login, que consulta um banco onde tenho as informações dos meu usuarios, se logado com sucesso, ele me manda para um form2, onde tenho informaçoes de empresa, e equipamentos cadastrados, porém, necessito de duas informações do form1, id-usuario, e id-empresa, pois no form2, tenho uma tabela que me traz quais equipamentos estão cadastrados para aquela empresa, e preciso do id do usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Se for isto que estou pensando é simples. Veja este exemplo:

```
    static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        Execute teste = new Execute();
        teste.DefineNome("Este é o novo nome", f2);
        f2.Show();
        Application.Run(f1);
    }
}

public class Execute
{
    public string DefineNome(string Nome, Form Formulario)
    {
        string novonome = "Completei" + Nome;
        Formulario.Text = novonome;
        return novonome;
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima temos dois forms. A classe Execute que criei possui um método que solicita qual é o formulário que será atualizado.
No momento da solicitação do método "DefineNome" eu passo dois parâmetros, o primeiro é um texto qualquer e o segundo é o formulário que já foi iniciado.
Lembrando que se este formulário de destino ainda não estiver instanciado vai ocorrer o erro "nulo" durante a execução do seu projeto

Comment: Amigo obrigado pelo exemplo, vou tentar realizar conforme me falou, hoje consegui resolver meu problema fazendo por constructor, porem, sei que não é o metodo recomendado para fazer isso. vou tentar melhorar e posto aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Galera obrigado pela ajuda.
Hoje, consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte:

no form1 eu adicionei dentro do meu metodo:

```
public void logar()
    {
        c_consulta.sqlconexão();
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(c_consulta.sqltring);

        usu = textBox1.Text;
        pass = textBox2.Text;

        int ret_eid = trazerid.retorna_eid(usu, pass);
        int ret_uid = trazerid.retorna_uid(usu, pass);
        //idchange(ret_eid, ret_uid);

        Tinicial telamenu = new Tinicial(ret_eid,ret_uid);
        telamenu.Show(); 
    }
```

No form2 eu adicionei no constructor:

```
public Tinicial(int ret_eid, int ret_uid)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label7.Text = Convert.ToString(ret_eid);
        dados_cliente(ret_eid);
        dados_usuario(ret_uid);                                
    }
```

Deu certo, porem, sei que não a melhor maneira de fazer isso, certo? vou tentar fazer por threads. se puderam me adiantar algum bom texto sobre, ficaria gradecido.

Obrigado gente